# How can I properly unit test a function that captures ConnectionError from the requests library

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-requests, pytest, python-responses

I have a function that makes a rest call with the requests lib

It should return "oh-no" to the caller if it cannot connect for any reason

I'm using responses for unit tests which should allow me to test this without actually making an outbound call

I can test this, this way:

```
# the function
def my_request(url):
    try:
        return requests.request(url=url)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        return "oh-no"
    except Exception:
        raise

# my test without responses
def test_request():
    bad_url = "https://lskjdklfjslkfjslkdf.eee.com"
    response = myapp.my_request(bad_url)
    assert response == 'oh-no'
```

But I'm wondering if the responses library can do this better?

```
# test with responses
@responses.activate
def test_request():
    bad_url = "https://lskjdklfjslkfjslkdf.eee.com"
    responses.add(
      "post",
      bad_url,
      json={"error": "not found"},
      status=500,
    )

    response = myapp.my_request(bad_url)
    assert response == 'oh-no'
```

Responses won't throw an exception here; I guess that's part of its purpose. Before I just use requests with a bad url to generate an exception in my unit test (which seems not too bad) I want to know if the responses library can raise an exception without making an outbound call. And also, if trying to do that is pointless (if I should just use requests like in first example and be done with it).

Comment: Why are you replacing an unambiguous error with a returned string which may or may not have been an actual response?

Comment: this is part of a system that tests endpoints for connectivity. It can't just throw an exception and exit it needs to capture that the endpoint was down so it can be reported. I guess "oh-no" should have been "down" to make that clear.

Comment: What's calling `my_request`? It can catch the exception (though it sounds like for your use, a string `"down"` is sufficiently unambiguous?).

Comment: i think its easier to test if the call to requests is in a more isolated function. also, the caller would have to implement all the logic of catching exceptions instead of just calling my_request and getting back what it needs

Comment: You can pass the connection error object in the `body` argument, there is an example of it in the [readme](https://github.com/getsentry/responses/blob/master/README.rst).

Comment: oh wow im dumb its right in the docs

Comment: @hoefling is there a way to have pytest dynamically cycle though all possible request exception types without manually specifying all of them?

Comment: You can parametrize the test with the list of exceptions as test arguments. Of course you can get the list of all exceptions by querying the module, e.g. `[cls for name, cls in inspect.getmembers(requests.exceptions) if inspect.isclass(cls)] and issubclass(cls, requests.exceptions.RequestException)` etc, but an explicit list is IMO a better and more readable solution.